# How to print slowly with a while loop in python 2.7.9

Tags: python, while-loop, timedelay

I am trying to print each iteration of the following loop more slowly (so that the person seeing the image printed can actually make out what it is before it goes away too quickly). Any help is welcome. The following code doesn't seem to slow anything down, even when I change the integer to a different number. I don't understand why it's not working.

```
 import time 
 while True: 

      print  """There are normally 55 lines of strings here, but for readability sake I have deleted them and inserted this text instead."""
 time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: You have a indentation problem, in `time.sleep(5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong indentation it should be

```
import time 

while True: 
    print  """There are normally 55 lines of strings here, but for readability sake I have deleted them and inserted this text instead."""
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the call to `sleep` is *outside* the while loop, you'll run *all* the prints, and only then sleep the program.

Indent the call to `sleep` to include it in your loop.

Comment: Wow >_> such a simple mistake. Thanks. I feel bad about even asking, but I guarantee you I would never have caught that on my own.